# Does the 'for in ' loop call function in Lua?

Tags: lua

There is a piece of code confuses me in [Programming in Lua](http://www.lua.org/pil/7.4.html)

```
local iterator   -- to be defined later
function allwords ()
  local state = {line = io.read(), pos = 1}
  return iterator, state
end

function iterator (state)
  while state.line do        -- repeat while there are lines
    -- search for next word
    local s, e = string.find(state.line, "%w+", state.pos)
    if s then                -- found a word?
      -- update next position (after this word)
      state.pos = e + 1
      return string.sub(state.line, s, e)
    else    -- word not found
      state.line = io.read() -- try next line...
      state.pos = 1          -- ... from first position
    end
  end
  return nil                 -- no more lines: end loop
end
--here is the way I use this iterator:
for i ,s in allwords() do
     print (i)
end
```

It seems that the 'for  in ' loop call the function iterator implicitly with argument state:
  i(s)

Anyone can tell me  ,what happened?

Comment: The right way to use above iterator is :for i  in allwords() do
     print (i)
end

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. Quoting [Lua Manual](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#3.3.5)

> The generic `for` statement works over functions, called iterators. On each iteration, the iterator function is called to produce a new value, stopping when this new value is `nil`.

The generic `for` statement is just a syntax sugar:

> A for statement like
>
> ```
> for var_1, ···, var_n in explist do block end
> ```
>
> is equivalent to the code:
>
> ```
> do
>    local f, s, var = explist
>    while true do
>      local var_1, ···, var_n = f(s, var)
>      if var_1 == nil then break end
>      var = var_1
>      block
>    end
>  end
> ```